# How to solve $X^TAX = B$ where each element of $X$ can only take $0$ or $1$ as their values

Tags: linear-algebra, constraints

I want to solve $$X^TAX = B$$ where $X$,$A$ and $B$ are matrices. $X$ is $n\times2$, $A$ is $n\times n$ (sparse), $B$ is $2\times2$, $x_{ij}$  is $0$ or $1$.and the row sums of X is $1$, What should I do ?

Comment: What are you solving for? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to solve for X, I had tried "grid search" to traverse all values of X , but it's too slow for me.